# width of an element within display table element (spoiler) forces word wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a spoiler with display:table for width to be auto shrinkend to contents. 
Now padding (padding: 1rem 3% 0.3rem 3%;) in spoiler contents forces the longest line to wrap, which is not needed.

Transition is also not working.
Creating a nested div haven't solved the problem so far
Is there a way to get transition work and get rid of word wrap?

```js
$(function splr() {
 $(".spoiler-toggle").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  var text = (this).firstChild;
  text.data = text.data ==  "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show";
 })
 $(".spoiler-all").on("click",function(f) {
  f.preventDefault();
  var slers = document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler-toggle");
  var textm = (this).firstChild;
  var b=true;
  if  (textm.data ==  "Expand all projects") {textm.data = "Hide all projects";} else
  {textm.data ="Expand all projects"; b=false;}
  for(var i = 0; i < slers.length; i++)
  { 
   var text = slers.item(i).firstChild;
   if (b){
    if (text.data == "Show") {
    //console.log(slers.length);
    $(slers.item(i)).parent().toggleClass('open');
    text.data = "Hide";}
   } 
   else {
    if (text.data == "Hide") {
     $(slers.item(i)).parent().toggleClass('open');
     text.data = "Show";}
   }
  }
 })
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 5% 3px 5%;
  display: table; margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
  /*white-space:nowrap;*/
}
.spoiler-header, .spoiler-toggle {
  line-height:normal ;
  display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;
}
.spoiler-toggle {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.spoiler > .spoiler-content {
  display: none; 
  margin-bottom:1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.spoiler.open > .spoiler-content {
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 3% 0.3rem 3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center">
  <button class="spoiler-all" style="margin: 0.3em 0;cursor:pointer;">Expand all projects</button>
  </p> 
<div style="max-width:84%;margin: 0 auto">
<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="spoiler-header">
  <h2  align="center"> First spoiler </h2></div>
  <button class="spoiler-toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="spoiler-content">
  <p><a href=//google.com/ style="color: black"> Just some line of text</a> - Problem wrapped</p>
  3 Lines of text. wrapping allowed
  <p> smaller line of text, no wrapping</p>
  6 Lines of text
</div><!-- spoiler content -->
</div> <!-- spoiler -->
```